# GPU in-use memory in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Is there anyway to query GPU device to find in-use memory with OpenCL? I want to allocate as much as memory that I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way of getting such information. Some alternatives (pretty poor alternatives, but anyway):

- CUDA provides such functionality via `cuMemGetInfo`
- `GL_ATI_meminfo` and `NVX_gpu_memory_info` OpenGL extensions
- `nvidia-smi` application